# Json.Net set the value of the Json object by mixed Json path

Tags: c#, performance, json.net

Code from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65715088/6859121

It is use a mixed Json path to set Json value. Even if the object on the path does not exist.
This code seems to have room for improvement.
Is there some way, logical or flow to do the same thing that I don't know?

```
//Origin code by Squirrel.Downy(Flithor)

using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public static void AddTokenByPath(JToken jToken, string path, object value)
{
    // "a.b.d[1]['my1.2.4'][4].af['micor.a.ee.f'].ra[6]"
    var pathParts = Regex.Split(path, @"(?=\[)|(?=\[\.)|(?<=])(?>\.)")
        // > { "a.b.d", "[1]", "['my1.2.4']", "[4]", "af", "['micor.a.ee.f']", "ra", "[6]" }
        .SelectMany(str => str.StartsWith("[") ? new[] { str } : str.Split('.'))
        // > { "a", "b", "d", "[1]", "['my1.2.4']", "[4]", "af", "['micor.a.ee.f']", "ra", "[6]" }
        .ToArray();
    JToken node = jToken;
    for (int i = 0; i < pathParts.Length; i++)
    {
        var pathPart = pathParts[i];
        var partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
        //node is null or token with null value
        if (partNode == null || partNode.Type == JTokenType.Null)
        {
            if (i < pathParts.Length - 1)
            {
                //the next level is array or object
                //accept [0], not ['prop']
                JToken nextToken = Regex.IsMatch(pathParts[i + 1], @"\[\d+\]") ?
                    new JArray() : new JObject();
                SetToken(node, pathPart, nextToken);
            }
            else if (i == pathParts.Length - 1)
            {
                //JToken.FromObject(null) will throw a exception
                var jValue = value == null ?
                   null : JToken.FromObject(value);
                SetToken(node, pathPart, jValue);
            }
            partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
        }
        node = partNode;
    }
    //set new token
    void SetToken(JToken node, string pathPart, JToken jToken)
    {
        if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            //get real prop name (convert "['prop']" to "prop")
            var name = pathPart.Trim('[', ']', '\'');
            ((JObject)node).Add(name, jToken);
        }
        else if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
        {
            //get real index (convert "[0]" to 0)
            var index = int.Parse(pathPart.Trim('[', ']'));
            var jArray = (JArray)node;
            //if index is bigger than array length, fill the array
            while (index >= jArray.Count)
                jArray.Add(null);
            //set token
            jArray[index] = jToken;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are my suggestions:

- Instead of hardcoding regex patterns inside the method call I would suggest to create separate const fields for them

```
const string pathRegexPattern = @"(?=\[)|(?=\[\.)|(?<=])(?>\.)";
const string jsonArrayRegexPattern = @"\[\d+\]";
```

- Then your `pathParts` initializer looks much cleaner

```
var pathParts = Regex.Split(path, pathRegexPattern)
    .SelectMany(str => str.StartsWith("[")
        ? new[] { str }
        : str.Split('.'))
    .ToArray();
```

- It is a matter of taste but you can use `foreach` loops here as well since you can also get the `index` variable like this

```
foreach (var (pathPart, pathIdx) in pathParts.Select((path, idx) => (path, idx)))
{
   ...
}
```

- Instead of having a huge guard expression for (null values) you can invert the if statement and have an early exit

```
var partNode = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
if (partNode != null && partNode.Type != JTokenType.Null)
{
    node = partNode;
    return;
}
```

- Then the most inner branching can be moved a bit outer
- The `else if` condition can be omitted as well since the first branch exists after its execution

```
if (pathIdx < pathParts.Length - 1)
{
    JToken nextToken = Regex.IsMatch(pathParts[pathIdx + 1], jsonArrayRegexPattern)
        ? new JArray()
        : new JObject();

    SetToken(node, pathPart, nextToken);
    node = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
    return;
}
       
var jValue = value != null
    ? JToken.FromObject(value)
    : null;

SetToken(node, pathPart, jValue);
node = node.SelectToken(pathPart);
```

- Finally I would suggest to define `SetToken` as a "normal" static method rather than a local one

```
private static void SetToken(JToken node, string pathPart, JToken jToken)
{
    if (node.Type == JTokenType.Object)
    {
        var name = pathPart.Trim('[', ']', '\'');
        var jObject = (JObject)node;
        jObject.Add(name, jToken);
        return;
    }

    if (node.Type == JTokenType.Array)
    {
        var index = int.Parse(pathPart.Trim('[', ']'));
        var jArray = (JArray)node;
        while (index >= jArray.Count)
            jArray.Add(null);
        jArray[index] = jToken;
    }
}
```